# How to create a hotkey to checkin selected files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I like to avoid using my mouse and visually searching for things. I want to be able to add a project that is selected in the solution explorer and all the changed nested files to my pending changes by assigning a keyboard shortcut to my keyboard commands. Which of the tons of commands do I need to use for that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard
- search for File.TfsCheckIn
- Assign the shortcut key.

For some reason this didn't work when I picked (ctrl+c, ctrl+c)